# ArgumentError (hour out of range) in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, activerecord, mysql2, rubyonjets

I have a problem with a legacy MySQL database that I'm not able to solve. I believe the culprit is that one of the fields has the wrong type set (it contains time in milliseconds, which the adapter doesn't expect having type DateTime), and unfortunately I can't change it.
What happens is this (using Ruby on Jets):

```
2.5.8 :001 > User.all.each {|u| puts u.inspect};mil
Traceback (most recent call last):
       16: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:250:in `records'
       15: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:626:in `load'
       14: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:808:in `exec_queries'
       13: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:839:in `skip_query_cache_if_necessary'
       12: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:821:in `block in exec_queries'
       11: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:46:in `find_by_sql'
       10: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:12:in `select_all'
        9: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:107:in `select_all'
        8: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:70:in `select_all'
        7: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:489:in `select'
        6: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:46:in `exec_query'
        5: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:210:in `execute_and_free'
        4: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:48:in `block in exec_query'
        3: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:48:in `to_a'
        2: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:48:in `each'
        1: from /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:48:in `utc'
ArgumentError (hour out of range)
```

I've tried to monkey patch this but I don't think I'm patching the right thing, it looks like the thing to change is the adapter (ouch...).
I've seen other changed ActiveSupport but it didn't work out for me, and basically I can't loop over my records without ActiveRecord crashing. I can't even rescue the problem, I don't know why but `rescue ArgumentError` doesn't get triggered by that exception.
Has anyone encountered this problem and managed to disable AR parsing of the records? It would be enough to get the value that crashes AR and `/ 1000` but I apparently can't find a way to do this.

Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = :user
  self.primary_key = :user_id

  alias_attribute :first_name, 'user_firstname'
  alias_attribute :last_name, 'user_lastname'
  alias_attribute :email, 'user_email'
  alias_attribute :phone, 'user_contact_number'
  alias_attribute :job_title, 'user_job_title'
  alias_attribute :contact_status, 'user_contact_status'
  alias_attribute :created_at, 'user_created'

  # has_one :settings, class_name: 'UserSettings'
  # has_many :cases, foreign_key: :created_by_user_id
  # has_many :subscriptions, -> { order('id DESC') }
  # has_many :orders, foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you didn't create this database in Rails? If that is the case, I wouldn't change the adapter, I would just change the column type to numeric or string and then add a method to your model that converts it to a DateTime.

Comment: @nzajt there's no rails involved, only AR. I have a `db/schema.rb` but I don't know how to do what you say, because it's AR/the adapter that inspects the table and "casts" to the right type. The db has been created with PHP

Comment: OK, that is good for you. In your Schema you should have a line that sets the type for this column something like `t.datetime "COLUMN_NAME"` you would just change datetime to string or numeric.

Comment: @nzajt I don't think schema.rb is used for that, I think it just populates the test db, but the typecasting is in real time

Comment: No, that isn't the case. Trust me I have been doing this for a long time. AR isn't magic and doesn't do real time typecasting. Database creation is done in the migration files. Give it a try.

Comment: @nzajt are we clear that I'm not creating any database but connecting to a legacy one? "Migrations, mighty as they may be, are not the authoritative source for your database schema. Your database remains the authoritative source." https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you

Comment: Anyway, if I remove the `schema.rb` completely it still fails, same thing if I change the datetime in the schema.rb to integer

Comment: What does your model look like? Can you add that file to your question?

Comment: I know you are connecting to an existing database, the schema file should show you what type it thinks the column is, with that information you can use that in your model to read the type. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545206/connect-rails-application-to-existing-database

Comment: @nzajt model is basically empty, connects to the database and that's it. The typecasting is the problem, the column as said is a DateTime, but the data is in millisenconds (hence "hour out of range"). I must override the typecasting of the DateTime. Added the model anyway.

Comment: So it is 'created_at' that is causing the issue?

Comment: Do you get the error when you comment out `alias_attribute :created_at, 'user_created'`

Comment: I don't think there's a way to know, there are a bunch of Datetimes (it is *very* legacy). The only way to have that ArgumentError I know is with Time.parse, that's why I think that's where the problem is (like "hour out of range"). Then, when I try to fetch an actual record without looping:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ngw/d620bba27790487a7d9ed6ddae8c595e (data is faked)

Comment: yes, I do get the error if I comment out that line. I get the error if I comment ALL the lines...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227216/discussion-between-nzajt-and-ngw).